# There is a metric space on $\mathbb{Q}$ such that this space be compact.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

Prove or disprove:

> There is a metric space on $\mathbb{Q}$ such that this space be compact.

I  find some examples of non equivalent metric on rational numbers, euclidean metric, p-adic and discrete metric but all of the them is not compact .

Comment: The question sounds incomplete.  What is "this space?"

Comment: The insight in jiagmath's answer is that the question you have been asked is *equivalent* to "is there a countably infinite compact metric space?". A similar idea can be used to answer questions like: "is there an operation on the set of prime numbers that makes it into a group?"

Comment: Note that any uncountable compact metric space is of size $\mathfrak{c}$, however. So a compact metric space can only be either finite, of size $\aleph_0$ or $\mathfrak{c}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a bijection between $\Bbb Q$ and the set $\{\frac{1}{n}\mid n\ge 1\}\cup \{0\}$ and use it to define the metric.